# How to extract files for a specific (conditioned) feature during administrative install

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I wrote a setup to install an add-in for an existing product (TFS); the extension API changed, so I have different versions of my add-in matching the different target product versions.

I used similar WiX code (full source [here](https://github.com/tfsaggregator/tfsaggregator/blob/master/Setup.Aggregator/Product.wxs))

```
<Feature Id='Server2013Feature' Title="Plugin for TFS 2013.5" Level='1' AllowAdvertise='no'>
  <ComponentGroupRef Id="NeutralServerComponents" />
  <ComponentGroupRef Id="ServerComponents2013"/>
  <Condition Level="1000">
    <![CDATA[TEAMFOUNDATIONSERVERVERSION<>"2013"]]>
  </Condition>
</Feature>
<Feature Id='Server2015Feature' Title="Plugin for TFS 2015 RTM" Level='1' AllowAdvertise='no'>
  <ComponentGroupRef Id="NeutralServerComponents" />
  <ComponentGroupRef Id="ServerComponents2015"/>
  <Condition Level="1000">
    <![CDATA[TEAMFOUNDATIONSERVERVERSION<>"2015"]]>
  </Condition>
</Feature>
```

Everything works fine except when I try an administrative install: I am not able to specify the target version via properties

```
msiexec /qb+ /L*v C:\admin-inst\admin-inst.log /a C:\admin-inst\TFSAggregator-2.1.178-Debug.msi TARGETDIR=C:\admin-inst\inst\ TEAMFOUNDATIONSERVERVERSION="2015.1"
```

I see in the log that Windows Installer extract all file version and the last extracted wins.

How can I have my cake and eat it too?

Answer (score 1):

I hope I'm not missing anything here but:

TEAMFOUNDATIONSERVERVERSION<>"2013" is true and:
TEAMFOUNDATIONSERVERVERSION<>"2015" is also true when it has the value "2015.1" so both features will get a level of 1000.